# Delete only certificates in big acme.json

Tags: bash, python, json

I am trying to figure out how to format big json file and delete only certificates from while which is formated like this:

```
{
  "http-01": {
    "Account": {
      "Email": "email@domain.tld",
      "Registration": {
        "body": {
          "status": "valid",
          "contact": [
            "mailto:email@domain.tld"
          ]
        },
        "uri": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/110801506"
      },
      "PrivateKey": "long_key_string",
      "KeyType": "4096"
    },
    "Certificates": [
      {
        "domain": {
          "main": "domain.tld"
        },
        "certificate": "long_cert_string",
        "key": "long_key_String",
        "Store": "default"
      },
      {
        "domain": {
          "main": "domain2.tld"
        },
      .....
```

I tryed `cat acme.json |grep certificate | awk ' { print $1 $2 } '` but I am strugeling how to select only text behing `"certificate":` and edit certificate between comas.

Is there elegant way to format this with bash/python? I was not able find a way.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do.  You say you want to delete `certificates` which is an array in your example, then you mention you want to select `certificate` which is a key inside the array, and edit that keys value.  Can you provide the desired output you are looking for?  Regardless though I'm quite certain `jq` is the tool you are looking for.

Comment: use `grep -B num Certificates > your new_json_file` num is a number oflines before certificate file.

Comment: I am trying to delete all certificate strings on every domain in this json file @jesse_b

Comment: Do you want to keep the certificates array and certificate key and just null out the value or delete that array altogether or delete that key altogether?

Comment: Make it null, so I will have in the document after editing output like

"certificate": "",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out jq and its man pages. Here's something to kick you off!

```bsh
jq '."http-01"."Certificates"[]."certificate"="OMITTED"'
```

Comment: Oh didnt knew this exists! Saved alot of work thanks! :)